# Как найти площадь и периметр круга в С#? Помогите пожайлуста

Tags: c#

Нужно найти площадь и периметр круга в C#

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Используйте формулу площади и периметра круга

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int radius;
Console.WriteLine("Введите радиус круга!");
radius = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Периметр круга = " + 2 * Math.PI * radius);
Console.WriteLine("Площадь круга = " + Math.PI * Math.Pow(radius, 2));
```

Comment: Ну два минуса без пояснений то за что? )